# Line numbers in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, line-numbers

I need to do a simple thing at first glance - add a bar with line numbers to CKEditor. The main idea is a writer can refer to a particular paragraph while discussing the text.

I have tried to find a plugin, tried to find an another WYSIWYG editor with line numbers but no success.

Does anybody know any solution for CKEditor or another one that already has line numbering?
Or the only I can do is to write it from scratch?

Thanks!

Comment: That's not simple at all. The content in CKEditor is so each line has different position. It isn't the same the first line of a paragraph than the second one, or the contents of a list or a table. If there's an image it might affect also the height of that line...

Answer (score 1):

I implemented it from scratch. When it will be possible I'm going to improve it. There are some issues and limitations now.

Link to [repository](https://github.com/shemigon/ckeditor-line-numbers-plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use the Codemirror plugin as well to get the Line numbers which includes search and replace as well.